# JQuery плагин validate, как выводить ошибку после родительского элемента?

Tags: javascript, jquery, плагин, jquery-validation

У меня есть код

```
<div class="block">
  <div class="input">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <div class="input">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <div class="checkbox-item">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <label></label> 
  </div>
</div>
```

label это у меня кастомный чекбокс. И проблема в том, что validate выводит ошибку после тега input в своем теге label. И поэтому в чекбоксах он добавляет свой label, что в результате добавляется еще один чекбокс сверху.
Подскажите как я могу вывести одну ошибку после тега `.checkbox-item`, а остальные оставить на своих местах

Answer (score 1):

Решение:

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
  if (element.attr('type') == 'checkbox') {
    error.insertAfter(element.parent());
  } else {
    error.insertAfter(element);
    }
  }
```